# Racket Scheme set-subtract Issues?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to use the set-subtract operator in Racket.  I have run into something I do not understand.  If I have the following code:

```
(set-member? (set "NDT_NT\\stuff") "NDC_NT\\stuff")
```

Shouldn't I get this as the answer?

```
#t
```

I am getting:

```
#f
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that it *should* be true—**iff** the two strings are the same. But they're not. One is ND**T**_NT and the other is ND**C**_NT.

Comment: Well. I am a prize idiot who cannot read. Sorry for wasting your time. ;-)